# the animation using onclick in jquery is not working in my browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to hide and show one of the content using a button and I tried to use `.on('click',...`, but nothing happens. When I add some function in JS like `alert()` it is working and I also tried to run it in w3Schools and it works. It is just not working in my browser when I open the HTML file.

The other that not inside the button or onclick function is working.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#btn1').on('click', function() {
    $('#panel1').hide(300).show(1000);
  });
});

$('#panel2').slideUp(1000).delay(1000).slideDown(1000);
$('#panel3').fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(1000).toggle(1000);
$('#panel4').fadeToggle(1000).slideToggle(1000);
$('.panel-body').css({
  color: 'red'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-1">
  <button id="btn1">btn1</button>
  <button id="btn2">btn2</button>
  <button id="btn3">btn3</button>
  <button id="btn4">btn4</button>
</div>
<div class="flex-box-panel">
  <div class="container-2">
    <div class="panel panel-primary" id="panel1">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        #panel1
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-3">
    <div class="panel panel-primary" id="panel2">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        #panel1
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-4">
    <div class="panel panel-primary" id="panel3">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        #panel1
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-5">
    <div class="panel panel-primary" id="panel4">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        #panel1
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code runs fine in the snippet I edited in to the question. My guess would be that you need to move ***all*** the logic inside the document.ready handler. The snippet, and tools such as jsFiddle and the W3S sandbox will automatically add this for you as it's generally required for jQuery to work properly

Comment: Look in the browser console and network tags (F12) for any errors.  This might happen if your HTML page has your script before including jquery (in which case you'd get an error)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I try to move it all inside the function and it have some error: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).slideUp is not a function`. And thank you for the resources you said to run my code.

Comment: The error implies that `$` is not a reference to jQuery, or that perhaps you're using jQuery slim instead of the full version.

Comment: @freedomn-m, I checked it and there is no error unless I put inside the `.slideUp()` in the function.